# Updating all components from a schematic library to schematic sheets with Altium instead of individually?

Tags: altium

As title suggests just wondering if there's a way to do this, like specially in case if I ever import this library to another project and want to update all my schematic components rather than having to update them 1 by 1 through the SCHLIB tab.

My Altium version is 19.1.6, and am looking to use the Update Schematic sheets function when you right click a SCH Library component, but to do more than one at once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like that:

On schematic page -> [Tools] menu -> [Update from libraries]